# Why does MySQL throw an error when calling a procedure

Tags: java, mysql

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Scanner;

class procedureTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/collection","collec","1234");
            CallableStatement stmt=con.prepareCall("{call getJob(?,?)}");
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter the id");
            int id=s.nextInt();
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2,Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.execute();
            System.out.println("job is"+stmt.getString(1));
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

//pl sql code(Procedure)

```
 DROP PROCEDURE `getJob`; CREATE DEFINER=`collec`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getJob`(IN `empId` INT(4), OUT `j` VARCHAR(20)) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER begin select job into j from emp where id=empId; end
```

why is this error coming?how to solve it?

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException**: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`j`)' at line 1`

help me out
please

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? That exception text doesn't seem to match your code...

Comment: @JonSkeet have added the procedure code

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getJob (IN empId INT(4), OUT j VARCHAR(20)) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER begin select job into j from emp where id=empId; end;
```

Comment: just using no '' and added delimiter ; after end. works fine for me